# Faillure sending email : Unable to read data from the transport connection:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Tags: c#

hi Dear all im getting issue

> InnerException = Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("info@electronichealthcaresystem.net", "mjaved39@gmail.com");
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.electronichealthcaresystem.net", 25);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@electronichealthcaresystem.net", "123");
    mail.Subject = "Testing";


    mail.Body = "testing";

    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}",
              ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: did you try to send an email using telnet? network credentials and parameters are double chekced?

Comment: Your ISP is probably blocking port 25.

Answer (score 0):

Since you set:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

The credentials you are setting in:

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@electronichealthcaresystem.net", "123");
```

are not being used. The default credentials (credentials of the currently logged in user) are being sent. This could cause the mail server to refuse the connection if the second set of credentials are the correct ones.

To use the second set of credentials set:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```